# How to Enumerate a generic List<T> without know the type

Tags: c#

I am passing a generic list to a function , i want to enumerate the objects in the list. If i able to enumerate items in list i will use reflection to the rest.

```
 var Items= new List<String>(){"s1","s2"};
  Enumerate(Items);
  void Enumerate(object items)
  {
        //i know the type so i  can cast and enumerate
        foreach(var item in (List<String>) items)
        {

        }
        // i don't know the type of object in the list
        //Following won't work , can't cast to List<object> 
        foreach (var item in (List<object>) items)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: shouldn't you be passing an IEnumerable<T> instead of Object?

Comment: how can i have the parameter type as IEnumerable<T> , The object passed to the function will always a List<T> , but the  type of object in List will be different

Comment: the bigger question is, why do you have different objects in the list? The usual way to accomplish this is with the Composite design pattern...

Comment: You don't need to know type just for enumeration. If you have to manipulate then you definitely need it. If you have to verify some different types of object with similar characteristics, then I would suggest you to use Interface and enumerate to that. like `foreach(var i in (List<IYourInterface>) items)...

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot: Even using an interface like this can be difficult pre-C# 4.0 if you don't have a `List<IYourInterface>` in the first place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure what your end-game goals are.  If you expect a list, specifically a generic list, why not go with a generic method, as in:

```
void Enumerate<T>(List<T> items)
{
  for(var item in items) 
  {
    //...
  }
}
```

This is described in more detail at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb(VS.80).aspx.

I just want to add that the above method, on its own, defeats the purpose of a simple for in loop.  Again, I don't know what Enumerate is meant to do above and beyond iterating over items.

Answer (score 7):

You can make your function generic

```
public void Enum<T>(List<T> list)
        {
            foreach (T t in list)
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The version of your function that works is:

```
var Items= new List<String>(){"s1","s2"};
Enumerate(Items);
void Enumerate<T>(List<T> items)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
    {
        //i know the type so i  can cast and enumerate
        foreach(string item in (List<String>) items)
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
        // i don't know the type of object in the list
        //Following won't work , can't cast to List<object> 
        foreach (T item in items)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But this can be written better as:

```
void Enumerate<T>(List<T> items)
{
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        { /* Do something */ }
        else
        { /* Do something else */ }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a static class where I have some utils functions like an string enumerator from a list:

```
public static string EnumerateStrings<T>(this List<T> items, string separator = "; ")
{
    var result = "";

    if(typeof(T) == typeof(string) && items.SafeAny())
    {
        items.ForEach(str => {
            try
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(str as string))
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                        result += separator;
                    result += str;
                }
            }
            catch { }
        });
    }

    return result;
}
```

And with this function you only need to use like this:

```
string myCarsEnumeration = Cars.Select(ob => ob.Name).ToList().EnumerateStrings();
//output-> Porsche; Lexus; Peugeot

//or

string myCarsEnumeration2 = Cars.Select(ob => ob.Name).ToList().EnumerateStrings(", ");
//output-> Porsche, Lexus, Peugeot
```

You can adapt to work with more object types.

The code of `SafeAny()`:

```
public static bool SafeAny<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return list != null && list.Any(predicate);
}
```