# C# 'type' is a variable but is used like a type

Tags: c#, reflection

This code throws an error `C# 'type' is a variable but is used like a type`

```
Type type = Type.GetType("Objects.Camera");
for (int i = 0; i < ((List<type>)currentObject).Count; i++)
{
 //...
}
```

currentObject is obtained with `.GetValue(object)` and has type object. I need to cast it to the proper type in order to use it as a list.

Comment: Your error is due to using the "type" variable as a actual type, have a look at the link to see how to do this: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a dynamic type List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860387/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-type-listt)

Comment: @peeyushsingh I don't think OP actually interested in that part (also it indeed explains the error). I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403443/how-to-enumerate-a-generic-listt-without-know-the-type may be more suitable, but it does not go into how to actually do anything useful with resulting iteration either...

Comment: This: `Type.GetType("Objects.Camera");` is wrong. `GetType` is an instance method on `System.Object` which is the base class of everything.  As a result, you can call that method on any object. But `Type` is a type (`System.Type`). You can't call GetType on the type `Type`. Assuming `Objects.Camera` is a type, you can access it this way `Type type = typeof(Objects.Camera)`

Comment: @Flydog57 You're talking about [`Object.GetType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype). He's using [`Type.GetType(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_GetType_System_String_).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that type is known right now, at compile time, then just cast it:

```
var list = (List<Objects.Camera>)currentObject;
```

However, I suspect the type actually comes from a runtime value, so you can't cast it. In this case you're out of luck: there's no way you can just cast to the right value, because a cast requires the type to be known at compile time.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you could resort to using reflection all the way:

```
var countProperty = currentObject.GetType().GetProperty("Count");
var count = (int)countProperty.GetValue(currentObject);

for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    // ...
}
```

However, that could get really unwieldy if you want to actually do anything useful with that list, because every operation on it would require using the reflection API, which would make the whole code less readable, less maintainable, and also slower.

Alternatively you could use `dynamic`, and that would make it less unwieldy, but it would still be slow and you still lose type safety.

So let's back up a bit. Maybe you only want to enumerate your list? Well, then, since you know your object is some kind of List, it means it implements several non generic interfaces that you can use:

```
var list = (IList)currentObject;
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    var item = list[i];
    // alternatively, cast currentObject to IEnumerable and use a foreach
}
```

With that, we've solved the problem of enumerating the collection, but not of actually using its contents, because `item` above will still be an object. You'll have to figure out a way around for that, because there's no general way of solving that particular problem, since it depends on what you're trying to achieve with the value.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Another somewhat standard approach is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403443/how-to-enumerate-a-generic-listt-without-know-the-type + using MakeGenericMethod to call generic iterator. Now... writing anything useful *inside* the method would be major pain unless one can restrict it to somewhat useful type...

Comment: I'd personally just go with `dynamic`, possibly wrapping iteration into a set of methods taking each `List<X>` I'm interested in and letting runtime to pick correct one.

Comment: Since he's using `Type.GetType("Objects.Camera")`, it sounds like the type is known at compile time and just casting to `List<Objects.Camera>` would work (or maybe just `List<Camera>` if the right `using` statements are already there - I suspect he's using the [EOS Digital SDK](https://github.com/Jossef/edsdk-wrapper).

Comment: @GabrielLuci you probably right about what they are using (based on another q - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57880881/how-to-sort-through-a-generic-list-object )

Comment: Perfect this worked, thank you

Answer (score 2):

C# `object.GetType()` doesn't work like `decltype` in c++.

It is evaluated at run-time, and returns the object's "most derived" type info. It is just like a normal function.

You are trying to use a run-time variable where a compile-time type name is expected.

Answer (score -1):

`List<type>` is the part that throwing exception, you created a **variable** named *type* to hold information about a specific Type and trying to use a variable as a **Type**

List<> expects a Type, not a variable!

Comment: Absolutely correct and completely useless for OP... Flagging as duplicate would be more appropriate if you don't want to explain what they *could* do to solve they problem.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov looking the question title _'type' is a variable but is used like a type_, I think this answer can be treated as completely relevant to the question at least, as the OP is apparently not aware of the actual exception origin. your point is appreciated though.